# How to fit Geyer saturation process for interaction between marks?

Tags: spatstat

I have two types of marks in my point pattern and I want to study the interaction between them. I am not sure if they are attractive or repulsive so I want to try fitting Geyer than MultiStrauss. As I understand, Hybrid gives for varying radii but not for different types of marks. I want to get the optimal interaction distance.

How do I effectively do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet implemented in the `spatstat` package.

In fact, some of the required statistical theory for multitype saturation models has not yet been developed.

I suggest you use empirical summaries such as `Kcross` or `pcfcross` or `Jcross` to assess whether the points are positively or negatively correlated, and then choose an appropriate model for that type of interaction.

Comment: Thanks! I think one can fit the Geyer separately for each mark as well as for the combined pattern. Would these three interaction radii's inequality say something about the interaction between the marks? Like if the combined interaction radii is smaller than each of the marks interaction radii, perhaps both marks interact heavily?!